# Overriding Ant Framework Css with Custom Css Issue

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a React component and I am integrating the Ant design framework on top of React. I have a Ant row with 3 columns. I also have a css file that has custom css in it. I want to take the custom css and add my css on top of it. None of the css i have in my css file is being implemented into the component when it renders.

Here is the react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Logo from '../../../static/images/bootup-logo.png';
import styles from './Topbar.css';
import Name from '../../static/images/bootup-name.png';

import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
render(){
    return(
        <div className="top-bar-container">
            <Row className={styles.topBarContainer}>
                <Col className={styles.imageContainer} span={6}>
                    <img className={styles.nameImage} src={Name} alt=""/>
                </Col>
                <Col span={12}></Col>
                <Col span={6}></Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the jsx and css file are in the same folder

here is the css that I am using:

```
.topBarContainer {
    background-color: #64B5F6; 
}

.imageContainer {
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.nameImage {
    height: 48px;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the css that I am trying to implement is not working and being implemented when rendering in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the stylesheet using `import "./styles.css";` and instead of using `className={styles.topBarContainer}`, do `className="topBarContainer"`.

See a working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n4vmvrj7yl

The problem here is that you did not export an object `styles` with the property `topBarContainer`, so you can't use it like one by using `styles.topBarContainer` in your component. Instead you have a normal CSS stylesheet, so you should import and use the styles like normal CSS by assigning CSS class to the component.